# How to construct a list of commands using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have python script `test.py` with the argument (input file name). I want to run it inside a shell script so that I can construct a list of commands (e.g `test.py --arg filename`) using `awk`. I have prepared `alist.txt` which contains file names in each line, I want python code to take it (list.txt) as an argument and go through each line (which is the names of files) and run it.

The following command is working fine but I want to include the test.py script with the arguments using the result of this command line.

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-11)}'  list.txt
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The main point is I wanted to know how I could use "awk" to make a list of the commands? something like this,                                                                                test.py --input filename | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-11)}'  list.txt

Comment: You want test.py to be a command, I assume? Not sure how you are feeding arguments in your code, but *argparse* has all you need to make some sweet commands. Including by default --help

Comment: Not sure if this clear but it's really difficult to state more than this, I'm just beginner of shell script.

Comment: I want to take the advantage of awk to prepare a list of my input files in one file(list.txt)  and pass it as an argument to my test.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to read each line output by your `awk` command in a loop, and call `test.py` with each line as a parameter:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-11)}' alist.txt |
while read -r; do
    test.py --arg "$REPLY"
done
```

Another solution is to use `xargs`:

```
awk '...' list.txt | xargs -L1 test.py --arg
```

---

[for the record: alternative answer, due to my misunderstanding of the question]

What I understand is that instead of having `test.py --arg alist.txt`, you want to have:

```
test.py --arg (file containing the result of your awk command)
```

In that case, you can save the result of your `awk` command in a file and give that file as a parameter to `test.py`:

```
awk '...' alist.txt > alist_processed_by_awk.txt
test.py --arg alist_processed_by_awk.txt
rm alist_processed_by_awk.txt
```

If you are using `bash` for your shell, another shorter way to do this is to use process substitution:

```
test.py --arg <(awk '...' alist.txt)
```

Here `<(command)` is replaced with the name of a pseudo-file that contains the result of `command`.

Comment: Maybe call system from inside awk?

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer : ). I'm just wondering about "$REPLY" in your answer, does that mean I have to pass my list.txt in the arguments? something like: test.py --input list.txt  "$REPLY".     because remember, I need to use the lines inside list.txt  as an input file every time to be processed by test.py.

Comment: @Jeff Yeah, there are plenty of solutions. It really depends on what the poster wants to do after (and before) each call to `test.py`, like testing the exit value and logging an error message, and so on (in this case, `xargs` wouldn't be suitable either)

Comment: @abubakryagob Your `list.txt` is already given as an argument to `awk`. What I use here is the result of you `awk` processing. `$REPLY` is only one line of that result. I have called `test.py` the way you showed us in your question (`test.py --arg filename`). Maybe I misunderstood something. In that case you should reconsider your question and give more details, for example: some lines of `file.txt` and how to precisely call `test.py` with the `awk` output

Comment: @xhienne you're just on point! This is exactly what I need (first answer), and the code is run correctly. Thank you very much : )

Comment: @abubakryagob Glad I helped. So the earliest answer was the good one and the update was not necessary?

Comment: @xhienne Yes! The earliest answer worked for me, but the updated one also helps me to understand in more details. I really can't thank you enough!